# Connecting with Blutooth Low Energy device. How to wait for BluetoothGattCallback methods to finish

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am new to Android and I have a project that connects an android device with other device with BLE. After connecting I have `mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices()` and I need to call `mBluetoothGatt.getServices()` after `onServicesDiscovered` is called. For now I am using this code:

```
@Override
public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
   if(status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS){
      servicesFound = true;
      Log.i("Send", String.valueOf(gatt.getServices().size()));
   }
}
```

and this is in the button click:

```
public void btnTestWriteOnClick(View v){
    if(mBluetoothGatt != null) {
        mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices();

        byte[] allBytesToSend = new byte[]{...};//Test byte array.

        List<BluetoothGattService> serviceList = mBluetoothGatt.getServices();
        while(!servicesFound){

        }
        servicesFound = false;
        displayGattServicesTest(serviceList, allBytesToSend);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

My `displayGattServicesTest`:

```
 private void displayGattServicesTest(List<BluetoothGattService> gattServices, byte[] allBytesToSend) {
    if (gattServices == null) return;
    //Sets the interval for printing.
    //ChangeIntervalAndTimeout();

    // Enable notification for characteristic.
    EnableNotificationInFFF4(gattServices);

    // Loops through available GATT Services.
    for (BluetoothGattService gattService : gattServices) {
        if (gattService.getUuid().toString().contains(serviceUUID)) {
            for (final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic : gattService.getCharacteristics()) {
                if (characteristic.getUuid().toString().contains(characUUID)) {

                    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    Log.i("Send", "===========================BEGINNING===========================");

                    int size = 19;
                    int times = allBytesToSend.length / size;
                    if (allBytesToSend.length > times * size) {
                        times++;
                    }

                    params = new byte[times][];
                    int tmp;
                    for (tmp = 0; tmp < 1000; tmp++) {
                        int logCount = 0;
                        for (int i = 0; i < allBytesToSend.length; i++) {
                            if(allBytesToSend.length < i + size){
                                size = allBytesToSend.length - i;
                            }
                            params[logCount] = new byte[size];
                            System.arraycopy(allBytesToSend, i, params[logCount], 0, size);
                            i += size - 1;
                            Log.i("Send", "====Sending command No " + logCount + "====");
                            logCount++;
                        }
                        WriteIntoPrinter t = new WriteIntoPrinter(characteristic);
                        t.execute(params);

                        try {
                            t.get(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            t.cancel(true);
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    Log.i("Send", "===========================DONE===========================");
                    Log.i("Send", "Tmp = " + tmp);
                    long difference = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                    Log.i("Send", "Time - " + (double) (difference / 1000) + " sec.");
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

My AsyncTask:

```
 private class WriteIntoPrinter extends AsyncTask<byte[], Void, Void>{
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic;

    WriteIntoPrinter(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic){
        this.characteristic = characteristic;
        //characteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(final byte[]... params) {
        for (int i = 0; i < params.length ; i++) {
            Log.i("Send", "Sending - " + i + " part. Number of bytes: " + params[i].length);
            characteristic.setValue(params[i]);
            mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);

            final int finalI = i;
            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (finalI == params.length - 1) {
                        Log.i("Send", "WaitingThread final - " + finalI);
                        while (!isWritingOnPaper) {
                            //SystemClock.sleep(20);
                        }
                        Log.i("Send", "WaitingThread final - " + finalI + " Done.");
                    }
                    else{
                        while (!isSuccessful) {
                            //SystemClock.sleep(20);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            t.start();
            try {
                t.join();  // wait for thread to finish
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            isWritingOnPaper = false;
            isSuccessful = false;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

**NOTE** This is only a test don't mind the for loops and the new Thread in the AsyncTask. Basecally in `displayGattServicesTest` I am splitting a `byte[]` into 19 byte arrays and sending it 1000 times to test the speed.

**NOTE 2** Dept Description: `displayGattServicesTest` take `byte[]` that is exactly 4*19 bytes long. After that it makes `byte[4][19]` and gives `byte[4][19]` to a AsyncTask that starts writing into the characteristic. Every time waits for `onCharacteristicWrite` to return true and when it writes the last [19] bytes waits for `onCharacteristicChanged` to return true and then writes the next `byte[4][19]`. This is the goal.

I do the same think when reading and writing.

This is working but I don't think this is the right way to do it. :) Is there any other way to wait `onServicesDiscovered`, `onCharacteristicWrite` and `onCharacteristicChanged` to finish successful.

Answer (score 0):

In your **btnTestWriteOnClick** just show progress bar, then wait for result in **onServicesDiscovered** , if you got result then hide progress bar and do your stuff (call displayGattServicesTest in onServicesDiscovered), you can disable button while discovering is in progress to prevent user from clicking it and starting new discover.

Comment: Yes, I thought about this but when I put `displayGattServicesTest` in `onServicesDiscovered ` I dont get `onCharacteristicChanged` triggered. I think this is because write and read are called from in the callback. If it helpes I will post my  `displayGattServicesTest` method. I use AsynTask  read and write there.

Comment: Please show us how you do your reads and writes then. You should never block one thread waiting for another thread to finish like this when you operate with Android BLE.

Comment: It looks complicated. What actually you want to do?

If you want to read/write characteristics after service is discovered after you are connected to device do it with callbacks. If you have somwhere code like while(notDone); it means that you are doing something wrong (it is designed to with callbacks/events etc and not block UI it isnt shell script)

Comment: There is a NOTE at the end that tells what I am trying to do but I will add in dept description

Comment: ok, sorry,   

wouldn't it better to increment some value when an action is triggered and decrement it in proper callback, this way you could every time check if the last work (write/read) were performed and then check currentTime?

Comment: I will try it but I don't think It will work. Or I am not getting the point.